# Best approach to change from identity(1,1) to identity(1,5)

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have some big tables with several million records and want to change the identity(1,1) to identity(1,5). what would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer yet?

i see a way like this on a in place migration:

```
SELECT *
INTO Backup_Table
FROM SOURCE_Table
GO
DROP Source_Table
GO
CREATE Source_Table (SerialNo IDENTITY(1,5) NOT NULL, ...)
GO
INSERT Source_Table(*)
SELECT *
FROM Backup_Table
GO
```

This has to be done for all the tables in a database.

What do you think?

Comment: On this approach one have to recreate all the constraints and indexes for new...

The better way is to get a full-SQL-script from the table and change the Value of identity-step from 1 to 5 with an editor (search & replace). But how to restore the data?